# how to list movie title in ascending order with same rating?

Tags: video, cs50

I am currently working on pset7 7.sql . Here is the link https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/7/movies/

Que:
write a SQL query to list all movies released in 2010 and their ratings, in descending order by rating. For movies with the same rating, order them alphabetically by title.

i have managed to solve first part of the problem.I can't figure out how to order movies title alphabetically with the same title.

Here is my code and output

```
SELECT     movies.title, 
           ratings.rating 
FROM       ratings 
INNER JOIN movies 
where      movies.id = ratings.movie_id 
AND        year = 2010 
ORDER BY   rating DESC;
```

[image: code output]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can combine fields in `ORDER BY` clause by separating them with a comma and it will respect the ordering order from left to right.

```sql
ORDER BY ratings.rating DESC, movies.title ASC
```

The above will...

- first order by `rating` descending (higher to lower)
- secondly order by `title` ascending (alphabetically)

Answer (score -1):

Mission complete

```
SELECT * FROM movies 
Movies INNER JOIN Boxoffice 
WHERE Movies.id = Boxoffice.Movie_id
ORDER BY Rating DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing! 
a couple of comments, A try to not solve someones homework with no context. a short explanation helps. 
Also, your choice of title case is a bit non standard. :-)